# file name or the location path does not get captured in the script when attaching a file in a Loadrunner Script

Tags: loadrunner, pega

I’m doing performance scripting on a Pega application using web http protocol, there is a step to brows & attach a excel file in the user flow. But when recording, the file name or the location path does not get captured in the script. The itemdata section in the particular post request is blank. Have anyone faced the same issue & have any solutions
LR version 12.02
Pega version: Pega 7

Comment: Is it possible that your attachment is not via HTTP and is being transferred via SMB or FTP?  Use Wireshark to confirm what protocol is being used for the attachment and how you will need to adjust your code appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things, browsing for a file and sending the file content. The operation of browsing for a file which is a functionality of your browser and not an HTTP operation. Once you select the file, the browser passes the **content** of the file to the website. As such, this operation will not be captured as getting a specific file from the disk and sending it.

What you can do in the script that will be equivalent to browsing for a file and sending it is using multipart file send.
For example:

`web_submit_data("do something", 
        "Action=<url of your website>", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "EncType=multipart/form-data", 
        "TargetFrame=", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=", 
        "Snapshot=t1.inf", 
        "Mode=HTML", 
        ITEMDATA, 
            "Name=name_of_files",           // form field name 
            "Value=c:/dummy/dummy.doc",     // value in Content-Disposition parameter of multipart message
            "File=Yes", 
            "ContentType=text/special",     // value in Content-Type parameter of multipart message
            "FilePath=dummy.txt",           // source path of upoaded file
            "ContentTransferEncoding=free", // value in Content-Transfer-Encoding parameter of multipart message
        ENDITEM, 
        LAST);`